# Почему prepend добавляет тег ко всем, а не только к первому из списка div-у?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот есть блок prblock с div-ами. Мне нужно только первый div из него выбрать и в него вставить картинку.

```
<div class="row prblock">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Специально выбираю из блока prblock только первый div, т.к. мне в него нужно вставить картинку. Но добавляется она во все div-ы из блока prblock.

```
var prtitleBlockFirst = $(".prblock").find(':first-child');
var imgspan = $('<span>').append('<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/v/img/pr1.png">');
prtitleBlockFirst.prepend(imgspan);
```

Почему так? Я же первый только выбрал и в него вставляю.

Comment: Сделай минимально воспроизводимый пример. Сейчас сложно понять о чём ты

Comment: вместо `$(".prblock").find(':first-child');` используйте `$(".prblock").children(':first')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".prblock").find(':first-child');
```

заменить на

```
$(".prblock>*").first();
```